# Executing Function/Stored Procedure in External DB using ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I am trying to execute a function in an external PostgreSQL db from my Rails 4 app. I cannot figure out how to do this.

I am connection to the external db as follows:

```
class Pgdb < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
  establish_connection :pg_development
end

class Mytable < Pgdb
  self.table_name = 'mytable'
end
```

I can query `Mytable` like this :

```
@info = Mytable.where("name LIKE ? AND amount > 0", "%#{params[:name]}%")
```

I cannot figure out how to execute a stored procedure since it isn't a `table`. Even though I tried to set the `self.table_name = my_stored_procedure` and querying `@info = Mytable.connection.execute("execute my_stored_procedure('#{params[:name]}')")`. Which gives an error: `ERROR: prepared statement "my_stored_procedure" does not exist`.

I have also tried:

```
@info = Pgdb.connection.execute("execute my_stored_procedure('#{params[:name]}')")
ERROR> PG::InvalidSqlStatementName: ERROR: prepared statement "my_stored_procedure" does not exist : execute agg_backs('JOHNSON, WALTER, PORTRAIT')


@info = Pgdb.execute("execute my_stored_procedure('#{params[:name]}')")
ERROR> undefined method `execute' for Pgdb(abstract):Class
```

How can I execute my stored procedure?

Comment: You need to call it in the same way as you would call it from `psql` which is `select my_stored_procedure(params)`. It does pay to read the [reference manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/xfunc-sql.html)

Comment: thanks! That worked.  I know that's how to do it in SQL, but sometimes in ActiveRecord it's different.

Comment: I get the same issue too. Actually in Postgres, you use SELECT ^^